# How to redirect complete domain to a particular folder

Tags: .htaccess

i want to rewrite url using .htaccess file, 
my all data is saved in work folder on server 
and i want to show that folder when user enter the complete webaddress

`www.example.com` to `www.example.com/work` using mod_rewrite

my code is

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /work/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

this code create problem when i enter somthing like `www.example.com/folder/` than it externally redirect me to `www.example.com/work/folder/` and shows 404 page not found even when work contains that folder and that folder contain index.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?work/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /work/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: same problem arrises when i enter www.example.com/login  than it redirect to www.example.com/work/login/ and says page not found.I have a login folder in work and that contains index.php

Comment: basically normal redirection works fine when i enter manual url in bar than this problem occurs...